# IE8 Sprite Sheet Backgrounds Disappearing

Tags: css, css-sprites

I am having some issues with these background images I am using for a menu on my app. In IE (7 and 8, maybe 9) the images seem to fall under the background of the item below it, which happens to have a black background. When I check the developer tools it seems that IE8 has created a css3 container to contain the image with z-index -1... I have changed the value in the developer tools to make it appear as normal, but then the text that is supposed to appear over the image disappears.... It is all rather frustrating.

It works fine in all other browsers.

Checkout: http://letswoosh.com

Anyone have any ideas about fixing this? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I disable Javascript using IE debugger and reload the webpage the images appear. Also when I load with Javascript enabled I get an exception in IE7 and 8 regarding _*e3* is null or not an object. The images disappear afterwards.

It's obvious the images are disappearing due to a Javascript error or incompatibility with IE.